# Useful or a waste of memory?

Tags: java, object, methods

In my class I we were assigned a problem to create a 'factorizer' application that calculates the prime factorization of any number up until a really large number. He gave us a `Number.java` class which calculates whether or not the number is prime or not for obvious uses.

```
// Number.java
public class Number {  
    long n;
    public Number(long number) {
        n = number;
    }
    boolean isPrime() {
        for(long k = 2; k < n; k++) {
          if(n % k == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that the `Number.java` class is that it has a constructor which in my mind makes it less 'mobile' in this situation. What I mean, is that in my loop to calculate the prime factors of the argument, a new Number object is being created over and over again. Wouldn't it make more sense to define a `private Number isPrimeFactor = new Number()` at the top rather than making a new `Number isPrimeFactor = new Number(i)` for every repetition of the loop? I asked my teacher about this but he isn't really answering. Here is some example code of what i'm talking about.

```
while (remainder!=0 && j<n) {
        Number isFactor = new Number(j);
        if(isFactor.isPrime() && remainder%j==0) {
            remainder = remainder / j;
            factor[i]=j;
            temp = (int) j;
            multiplicity[temp] = multiplicity[temp]+1;
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, you only need a specific subset of Number, Integer and Long. Float and Double make no sense. Btw, to check if a number n is prime, no need to check if numbers bigger than n/2 are divisors, since given n, there are no divisors bigger than n/2.

Comment: `k` only needs to go up to `sqrt(n)` which will be faster for large `n`. With respect to the loop and creating objects, let Java's garbage collector handle that.

Comment: This smells a lot like premature optimisation. It looks like you are going to be making possibly hundreds or thousands of divisions per number yet are thinking about the little overhead in creating the initial Object.

Comment: I fear you (and others) may be missing the point. Clearly the routine should be static and can be optimised to limit k to n/2, but this isn't the objective of the task. You might earn extra credits for mentioning these (notice the teacher was coy about responding when questioned) but they're a side issue...

Comment: @RobbieDee: no extra credit in this class. he doesn't even check our code. we upload our code to his website where an ant script compiles our code and compares our output against his. we get points based on how close our output is to his

Comment: In which case it makes even less sense to worry yourself unduly about it...

Comment: @yshavit: Completely agree. makes sense to me but again, the `Number` class was _his_ doing, not mine.

Comment: @pattmorter I understand how these things work. :) Wasn't blaming you for it, just a general heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `new` are rather expensive, meaning that calling a few thousand times `isPrimeFactor = new Number(j)` is less efficient than having just one instance of `Number` and changing the associated `n` value with, say, a `isPrimeFactor.setN(j)`. That's because `new` allocates fresh memory, and that memory is released from time to time by the garbage collector once the instance is not reachable anymore.

The advantage of making Number immutable, though, is that you don't risk habing one piece of code change its value while another one thinks it hasn't changed (very good property when you are using threads, for example).

By the way, I think that `Number` class given by your professor is an awful OO design, mutable or not.

Comment: I agree, his `Number` class is an awful OO design.

Comment: Just curious, are you saying it's awful OO because all its only functionality is to check if a number is prime which could be better suited as a simple static method?  Assuming that a Number would have additional functionality, the OO seems fine. Only change I would do is, since it's immutable, cache the result of `isPrime()` once it was calculated the first time.  And possible expose a `static isPrime(long)` convenience method that `isPrime()` would delegate to.

Comment: @Blake, yes, if you add other functionalities to the `Number` class, then it can become a good design, provided the result for `isPrime()` is cached, as you suggest. I just supposed pattmorter had given us the whole class definition.

Comment: yes, that was the whole class definition for the `Number` class he gave us.

Answer (score 1):

What would make sense here is **not** having a constructor with the sole purpose of passing `n` to `isPrime()`: that's what function arguments are for!

```
public class PrimeChecker {     
  public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    for(long k = 2; k * k < n; k++) {
      if(n % k == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always a choice between memory/speed/code readability/maintainance. Therefore it's not possible to answer the question in an objective way.

Is this solution inefficient? Maybe, but then again, function calls are expensive so any solution involving function calls could be labelled as inefficient.

If this is homework or a learning excercise then code efficiency is not very important, but making clear code that explains the concepts involved is very important!

Ps.

Most code I've seen which checks for prime numbers have a method "isPrime" that takes a number/integer as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Other optimizations aside, there's no reason to create a Number, Integer, etc. for these.  You can skip all of the above with this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(long number) {
    for(long k = 2; k < n; k++) {
      if(n % k == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: yes i know that but my teacher is one of the "Real Programmer" guys and wants us to do OOP rather than procedural in every case. i know OOP is good practice but it sames wasteful here but he doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely be faster to only instantiate the number once and assign its field repetitively. However, in this case the test `isPrime` is probably the bottleneck, so you will hardly notice the difference.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct, allocating objects inside a loop is a performance anti-pattern.
instead you can boost the speed of execution and improve memory usage by making use of static class members.

```
// Number.java
public class Number {  
  private static long n;
 public static void setNumber(long number){
        n = number;
 }
 static boolean isPrime() {
     for(long k = 2; k < n; k++) {
       if(n % k == 0) return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your answer... What has static to do with the question?

Comment: @m0skit0 static means single instance of the class and its objects thus saving memory and static methods are faster to access than object methods

So he saves both memory and speed

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is a far bigger anti-pattern than allocating objects within a loop. Constructing an instance of an object and then setting that value in a static field is very dangerous, completely non-thread-safe, and non-intuitive. It's not even safe in single-threaded contexts

Comment: @Blake The question was clear about saving memory and processing speed in a specific scenario , in the above defined case I think static methods and variables are the best options.

Comment: Even if this class was used **only** by this one method, thereby ensuring that it is used strictly sequentially, you'd be better off at that point creating a simple `static boolean isPrime(long)` method.